# Replicating and differentiating portions of a form

Tags: javascript, html

UPDATE:
Using the code that colecmc provide(Thank you!!) I updated the codepen. I like how the date.now is added, but I would like to just do a an incremental increase. Im not sure how to apply that to this function I tried zer00ne's index incremental but am doing something wrong.

```
let cloneList = [],
    index = 0; // index must be declared apart from function or else you will set it to the initial value every time the function is called.

document.getElementById('launch').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
  var container = document.getElementById('add-components')
  var clonedNode = addOnDiv.cloneNode(true);
  var component = clonedNode.querySelector('input');
  index++;
  clonedNode.id = index+1;

  cloneList.push(clonedNode.id);

  component.id = `componentID_${clonedNode.id}`;
  component.name = `componentName_${clonedNode.id}`;

  container.appendChild(clonedNode);
}
```

Im having an issue with my form. Initially I had two forms on the page. However on submit only the info from the first form was written. I tried combining the forms. Now if i fill out the campaign and component inputs and submit it writes to the correct tables(good!). However the component section is supposed to be replicated. A campaign can have as many components as the user wants. I am using cloneNode and before I combined the table it added more component sections. Now that they are combined the function no longer works. Im confused if this is even the right approach for what Im doing. I included a copdpen that shows a stripped down version of what Im trying to do.

Basically I want to be able to press add component, add as many new components as I'd like fill them out and have then all written as records to the db. I need a way to differentiate all the clones (new ids or names?)
codepen: https://codepen.io/anon_guy/pen/VMZWWW?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-event" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name" placeholder="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" value="address" placeholder="address" id="address" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="phone" placeholder="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" />
        <div class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="add_component">
    <button id='launch'>Add Component</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id="add-components">
  <div class="panel panel-default " id="addon">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label>component</label>
          <input type="text" name="component" value="component" placeholder="component" id="component" class="form-control" />
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('launch').onclick = function() {
      var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
  var container = document.getElementById('add-components')
      var clonedNode = addOnDiv.cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(clonedNode );
    }
```

Comment: IIRC, you will need distinct names for each form element.  So "component" would probably want to become "component1".

Comment: *"... Im not sure how to apply that to this function I tried zer00ne's index incremental but am doing something wrong."* First @colemc 's answer rely's on `cloneNode()` as does your OP (Original Post) code. My code does ***NOT CLONE*** anything. It takes a simple or complex text string and parses that string into real HTML. So when you construct 1 element with 3 lines for 3 attributes and then use `appendChild()` and then add another element within it = 6+ lines of code. My way you would find a target `insertAdjacentHTML()` = 2 lines of code, and it's faster.

Comment: colemc's code uses timestamps which by it's very nature doesn't need to be incremented because it is a linear progression akin to incrementing **but** it is not a constant unit of measurement. `Date.now()` = (`comp+timestamp, comp+timestamp+128ms, comp+timestamp+67ms, comp+timestamp+N?`). An incremented count = (`comp+1, comp+2, comp+3...comp+N`) So to combine timestamps and an incremental count is pointless. To apply my code to your or colemc's is pointless, you either use one or the other or have a better understanding of what you want and what is possible, and the wisdom to compromise.

Comment: In reference to Update 2: You are mired in what you are already using (OP),  consider your objective, backtrack through the steps taken, then identify the issue and what steps were taken to get to that point. With the added requirements, you might be *"painting yourself into a corner"*? You need to approach your objective keeping reusability in mind. It's obvious that you need a modular and reusable function because your question has evolved drastically (either that or you are not clarifying your objective very well).

Comment: To simplify: Post an example of the HTML as it should be before any duplication. Next, post the HTML that is the result of clicking the button twice. Also, add what expect in the console on each step for the returned array. So on stage 2 (first click) and stage 3 (second click) should show **exactly** what is expected for ids and names for each element. If you do this, you'll probably resolve it yourself, if not I can try to help.

Comment: I found a different solution. The clone function isn't working the way id like. Like you said, I was painting myself into a corner. New solution not perfect yet but is allowing for unique ids and names for all inputs. in addition to a remove button for each line. Your comments have been helpful.

Comment: You have the right idea with editing your question to add additional information, but there's a natural limit to how long you can keep doing this. Once you have received answers to your question, and you're really asking a *follow-up* question, that should be a new question, rather than an edit. I've rolled back your latest edit, as that appears to be a brand-new question, unrelated to the answers you've already received. If you're still having this problem, please ask a new question, providing a link to this one for context, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to try something like this before appending to the container `clonedNode.id = Date.now();`

That will provide a way to differentiate all the clones by giving a unique id. You can take it a step further like this:

```js
let cloneList = [];
document.getElementById('launch').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
  var container = document.getElementById('add-components')
  var clonedNode = addOnDiv.cloneNode(true);
  var component = clonedNode.querySelector('input');

  clonedNode.id = Date.now();
 
  cloneList.push(clonedNode.id);

  component.id = `componentID_${clonedNode.id}`;
  component.name = `componentName_${clonedNode.id}`;

  container.appendChild(clonedNode);
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-event" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name" placeholder="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" value="address" placeholder="address" id="address" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="phone" placeholder="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" />
        <div class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="add_component">
    <button id='launch'>Add Component</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id="add-components">
  <div class="panel panel-default " id="addon">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label>component</label>
          <input type="text" name="component" value="component" placeholder="component" id="component" class="form-control" />
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The components still have identical `#ids`, but the duped `.panel-default`s are serialized nicely.

Comment: I like this but the ids dont change, also how could i add unique names in addition to  ids?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. I guess this is what @zer00ne was referring to. Please look at the update

Comment: I like the timestamping it looks cold and impersonal like a machine should be. I have id and name of each component  in their respective sequential index number (boring).

Comment: works now thank you!! thats cool, I want to change the time stamp to just a index number like zer00ne,  tried adding this, but is doing the +1 so any component after 2 is still labeled as _2                                                                      var index = 0;

    index++;

    clonedNode.id = index + 1;

Comment: That was not a part of your original question. Update the question and add as much clarity as you can.

Comment: @Anon_guy, that's the beauty of the Unix timestamp, each one is unique as a snowflake but the downside is there's no solid pattern for counting although sorting would still be feasible. *"...but is doing the +1 so any component after 2 is still labeled as _2 var index = 0; index++; clonedNode.id = index + 1; ..."* Huh?? That made no sense 0_o??!

Comment: yeah the stamp is cool but not for this application. I need the new inputs to have the same name and id just with an incremental attached. currently the whole name and id are being replaced

Comment: @Anon_guy if you run my answer then view the results on console, you'll see each row having `id='component1'` `name='component1'` `...id='componentN'` `...name='componentN'`

Comment: what if it was multiple inputs? Like [id='component_name' name='component_name'] and [id='component_type' name='component_type'] , etc. ? the codepen has been updated to show what Im going for

Comment: You have a completely different question now, from what was originally posted.

Comment: @Anon_guy once again you have totally lost me with incoherent pseudo-code. so I stared at it's deeper meaning until my eyes were bleeding **T-T**. What you are proposing is an inefficient way of handling arbitrary data. Attributes were not meant to store 5MB of useless garbage, use `data-*` for extra data. So your **FINAL** question is ,*"How would something like zer00ne's  answer or @colecmc's answer be refactored to clone an input field and assign a unique id, name, `data-type`, `data-useless`, `data-50-questions`, etc.. attributes?"*

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I came to what I believe is your way of thinking by looking at your code. (I  also removed  some unnecessary steps in your code to  make it a little bit cleaner). This is for if you must have different names and ID:s on your inputs. However, if you can manage to have the same for both (i.e. component_0, other_0 etc.), you can remove the "names" array and the "names" forEach.

When you want to add an input to your addon-div, just add the ID (and name if you decide to keep it), without the "_0", to the array/s as in the example.

Change the name to "otherName_0" and ID to "otherID_0" in your html and this should work.

```
var i = 1;
document.getElementById('launch').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
  var container = document.getElementById('add-components')
  var clonedNode = addOnDiv.cloneNode(true);
  var ids = ['componentID', 'otherID'];
  var names = ['componentName', 'otherName'];

  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    var currentInput = clonedNode.querySelector(`#${id}_0`);
    currentInput.id = `${id}_${i}`;
  });

  names.forEach(function(name) {
    var currentInput =  clonedNode.querySelector(`input[name=${name}_0]`);
    currentInput.name = `${name}_${i}`;
  });

  container.appendChild(clonedNode);
  i++;
}
```